# How can I reliably open a page in a new tab using Google Closure libraries?

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-library

I had tried to open a page in a new window with

```
goog.window.open('/urlToOpen', {
      "location": false,
      "menubar": false,
      "statusbar": false
  });
```

However, Google Chrome's popup blocker prevented me from doing so when this code executed.

Google docs open in new tabs for editing. Can I similarly open a new tab with Closure?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried executing your code as a callback to a user-driven browser event e.g. a button click? Chrome suppresses the opening of new windows/tabs otherwise.

```
<a class="link" href="#">Some link</a>
```

Try it out in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LnFNt/2/).

```
$('.link').click(function() {
  goog.window.open('/urlToOpen', {
    "location": false,
    "menubar": false,
    "statusbar": false
  });
});
```